# Java oop design verification

Tags: java, oop

I have been reading up on Java and oop design. One of the exercises was to design a system to hold astronomical objects and some basic attributes of them.

the system needs to hold Stars, Galaxies and Planets.

Each Object has a type, eg for stars; dwarf, giant and normal

Starts also have a colour.

So far I started with a abstract base class for all these objects called AstronomicalObject:

```
public abstract class AstronomicalObject {
  //Is this totally pointless?
}
```

I then made 3 classes Star, Galaxy and Planet that extend this class. For each type of these Objects I made additional subclasses ie DwarfStar that extends Star. Is this an acceptable idea? The additional classes feel slightly redundant:

```
public class DwarfStar extends Star{
  public final String SIZE = "DWARF";
  public DwarfStar(String colour) {
    super(colour);
  }
}
```

For the colour attributes I did this:

```
public class Star extends AstronomicalObject{
  public final static String YELLOW = "YELLOW";
  public final static String RED = "RED";
  public final static String WHITE = "WHITE";
  public final static String SIZE = "NORMAL";
  private String colour;

  public Star(String colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
  }

  public String getColour(){
    return this.colour;
  }
}
```

So to create a star object I would use:

```
DwarfStar ds = new DwarfStar(Star.YELLOW);
```

Unfortunately the book doesn't have an answers page or discuss this exercise so I was wondering if my solution was valid oop design. Or if it could be improved upon?

Comment: it is better to use enum instead of string constants

Comment: I think in this simple excercise it is not necessary to subclass the Star class. If the only use is to add the field SIZE it would be a better approach to create a field 'type' in the Star class. This can be realized with an enum. In my opinion you should only use inheritance if you really need it, because it increases complexity.

Comment: @Don I was also thinking this and I have changed it to that and it has made it much cleaner. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this totally pointless?

if your three objects have a `type` as you said, then no it isn't useless as you will be able to write only one setter and getter in your superclass instead of implementing it in each subclass. In fact a superclass is not useless if every subclasses have a common property.

Then for the colours you could use an [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of static variables:

```
public enum Colours{
    YELLOW, RED, WHITE, NORMAL
}
```

and access them with `Colours.RED` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the enum, that is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is very valid and there are, if any, just minor improvements.

The `AstronomicalObject` Class seems pointless at this Point, but should be kept if you want to add something in the Future, or if you decide that every Astronomical Object has a mass or shape or whatever. Also in bigger software solutions this could be neccessary.

Answer (score 2):

I think as this is an OOP exercise it is important to consider what planets stars, and galaxies have in common. Maybe color only applies to stars and planets? What about size? You might want to redo this exercise thinking more about how you can describe the attributes of your classes in this way

Answer (score 1):

Composition is used more than inheritance in OO design. So, a `Galaxy` is composed of `Star`s and `Planet`s. Your code should show that. Does a `Planet` always belong to a single `Star`? If so, then you should show that somehow.

Other answers point out that sub-typing `Star` is not necessary for the trivial cases you gave, but might be if you considered [all the categories of astronomical objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_object#Categories_by_location). I think the `AstronomicalObject` is only really necessary if there is truly some function or characteristic that is common to all subclasses.

It sounds like you're starting out, so the exercise is to get you familiar with composition and inheritance. A caveat of OO design exercises that model real-world objects is that they don't give you the requirements of the *software* you're designing. Yet, those requirements are *very important* when make the OO design model. For example, if the software you're designing is supposed to catalogue celestial objects visible to amature telescope users, adding a class for BlackHole (assuming they are not visible with amature optical telescopes) might be unnecessary.